# In which data type text data extracted from news site should be stored for NLP?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, nlp

I extracted following text data using `beautifulsoup`

```
for data in soup2.find_all(class_="td-post-content"):
         data.get_text()
```

In which type of data type should I store above extracted data?

I stored above extracted data into the list but cant perform text analysis
it does not contain any headline etc..

Answer (score 0):

The question is still a little unclear and could definitely do with some improvement.

---

You can save the scraped content (`str`) in a `list` of `dicts` on which you then perform the NLP operations or go one step further and convert it to a `dataframe` beforehand.

However, as already mentioned, you must select the relevant content yourself and add it to your result.

###### Example based on cancer.org

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = f"https://csn.cancer.org/categories/prostate"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

data = []
for e in soup.select('ul.linkList li'):
    data.append({
        'url':e.a.get('href'),
        'title':e.a.text,
        'content':e.p.text
    })

pd.DataFrame(data)
```